# How do I get this unexecuted line of code to execute?

Tags: java, object, methods

I have an "Appointment" class as follows

```
private String month;
private int day;
private int hour, minute;
private String message;

Appointment() {
    month = "Jan";
    day = 1;
    hour = 12;
    minute = 0;
    message = "message";
}

private void setMonth(String monthIn) {
    if (monthIn.length() > 3) {
        System.out.println("Re-enter and keep month to 3 letters");
    } else {
        month = monthIn;
    }
}

private void setDay(int dayIn) {
    day = dayIn;
}

private void setHour(int hourIn) {
    hour = hourIn;
}

private void setMinute(int minuteIn) {
    minute = minuteIn;
}

private void setMessage(String messageIn) {
    message = messageIn;
}

public void inputAppointment() {
    System.out.println("Input appointment (month, day, hour, minute, message)");
    setMonth(UserInput.getString());
    setDay(UserInput.getInt(1, 31));
    setHour(UserInput.getInt(1, 12));
    setMinute(UserInput.getInt(0, 59));
    setMessage(UserInput.getString());
}
```

In my main method i have

```
Appointment app = new Appointment();
app.inputAppointment();
```

But I'm only able to input the first string and the following 3 integers. setMessage(UserInput.getString()); never executes.
The arguments sent to the set methods in inputAppointment() call methods from a "UserInput" class that handles input as follows

```
public static String getString() {
    return scan.nextLine();
}

public static int getInt() {
    return scan.nextInt();
}

public static int getInt(int min, int max) {
    int input = getInt();
    if (input >= min && input <= max) {
        return input;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Re-enter...");
        return getInt(min, max);
    }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your UserInput class I can't be certain, but this sounds like the issue of using `nextLine()` after using `nextInt()` and consuming the newline without accepting further input - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/1828486) for more info.

Comment: Thanks this link was helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time the user inputs text into the console and presses enter, the user's input plus the end of line characters '\r\n' are added to the input buffer.

`scan.nextLine()` reads to the next '\r\n' characters and returns what it found.

`scan.nextInt()` will read ahead until it has scanned in the next int, but it will not consume the '\r\n' from the user pressing enter. After your 3rd call there is still a '\r\n' on the input buffer and your next call to `scan.nextLine()` assumes this is the user's next line of input.

If you are expecting the user to enter an integer on separate lines, then you need an extra call to `scan.nextLine()` to consume the end of line characters.

i.e.

```
public static int getInt() {
    int input = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    return input;
}
```